# Save a python dictionary as a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a dictionary which looks like the example I've mentioned below. I need to save it as a json file in the same format without changing the data types to a string value so that it can be imported later on to validate the data type of the parameters used.

```
data = {
    'model':{
        'param1': tuple,
        'param2': tuple
    },
    'model2':{
        'param3': int,
        'param4': bool
    }
}
```

It is being used like this:

```
isinstance(some_value, data['model']['param_1'])
```

Here some_value is the value for which we need to check the type.

Comment: it's a nested dictionary tho

Comment: JSON has int and bool datatypes, but tuple isn't a thing. JSON serialization will turn your tuples into lists.

Comment: If your values are not converted to valid JSON types then your output won't be JSON. Does your output have to be JSON? Have you considered *pickle*?

Comment: It's impossible to convert values like `tuple` or `bool` to JSON, so if you want to use JSON you'll have to convert them to a different representation, for example strings. This still allows you to use the `isinstance` checks that you want, so long as you convert them back to the original type from the serialized representation.

Comment: Saving dictionary as a pickle file does this job. Thanks @LancelotduLac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this was already covered in the comments...

Unfortunately the only data types that can be stored in a json file are those that are described in the JSON specification, which includes arrays, objects, strings, numbers, booleans and null.

When you `load` a `json` file in using pythons `json` module, it automatically converts certain JSON Data Types into the python equivalent. e.g. `arrays` turn into `lists`, `objects` turn into `dicts`, `strings` remain `strings`, `null` becomes `None` etc... so what you are asking is kind of impossible.

There are of course ways around this, such as instead of storing `tuple` which is a `type` object in python, you can instead store the "tuple" keyword as a string and then write some conversion logic you can run when needed.

Probably a better alternative though is to use the `pickle` module.  The api is identical to the `json` module, and it can store all python data types with ease, including custom classes in most cases.  Pickled files are not human readable unfortunately, but your use case doesn't sound like that is a requirement.

Here is a link to the documentation on the pickle module.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a json file, I converted the nested dictionary to yaml file and then later used it to check the data types of the supplied parameters.